# Replicate Hackernoon url effect css

Tags: html, css

New to html/css and would like to reproduce the effect here on urls. See the first url in the article "W3 Schools" which has an offset pale green bar and then goes solid on hover.

https://hackernoon.com/most-useful-sql-resources-f8q3254

An explanation of which properties do what would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can right click and inspect that element to see what properties applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using transition and background-position

```css
strong:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent calc(50% - 9px), rgb(0, 255, 0) calc(50% - 9px), rgb(0, 255, 0) 100%);
    background-position: 0px 100%;
}

strong {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent calc(50% - 9px), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.35) calc(50% - 9px),
  rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.35) 100%);
  transition: background-position 120ms ease-in-out 0s, padding 120ms ease-in-out 0s;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}
```

```html
<strong>W3 Schools<strong>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really close. The urls on the site have the bar offset and it appears to transition from the bottom up. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: @Oaty Found a way!

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this class to your `<div>`

```
myClass : {
    "borderBottom" : '3px solid rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    "transition" : 'all .8 ease-in-out',
    '&:hover': {
     "background" : "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    }
```

Comment: um, could you please give more explanation about how can I apply it and where I can write this code ( it doesn't look like css)

Answer (score 0):

I'm none the wiser but this appears to work.

```css
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(60, 60, 59);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

a:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent calc(50% - 9px), rgb(0, 255, 0) calc(50% - 9px), rgb(0, 255, 0) 100%);
    background-position: 0px 100%;
}

.flashy {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent calc(50% - 9px), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.35) calc(50% - 9px),
  rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.35) 100%);
  transition: background-position 120ms ease-in-out 0s, padding 120ms ease-in-out 0s;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: 2px 0px 1px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="flashy">Flashy URL</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS

```
   a{
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#ffffff;
    }
    a div{
      width:100px;
      height:50px;
      background:#a8ee67;
    }
    a div:hover{
      background:#0bc704;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <a href="">
    <div class="text-center">
      Hover me
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```